# Javascript function like php POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input form builded with Bootstrap. The check of correct data is handled by javascript, and it's set that on click of button "remind me" it pop ups a notification that says that everything is correct. This last part of pop up notification is handled by php POST method, and I want the same pop up to be shown but with javascript instead of [php](/questions/tagged/php).

The HTML is:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="registerHere" method='post' action=''>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="user_name" name="user_name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name" placeholder="First name Last name">

      </div>
</div>

 <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="user_email" name="user_email" rel="popover" data-content="What’s your email address?" data-original-title="Email" placeholder="me@somewhere.com">

      </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <input type="text" class="span1" id="inputPLZ" name="inputPLZ" placeholder="Postal" data-content="Insert your area postal code.">
    <input type="text" class="span2" id="inputOrt" name="inputOrt" placeholder="Place" data-content="Where are you from?">
</div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input01"></label>
      <div class="controls">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">Remind me</button>

      </div>

</div>



  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and the Javascript is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#registerHere input').hover(
            function(){
        $(this).popover('show')
            },
            function(){
        $(this).popover('hide') 
            }
        );
        $("#registerHere").validate({
            rules:{
                user_name:"required",
                user_email:{
                        required:true,
                        email: true
                    },
            },
            messages:{
                user_name:"Enter your first and last name",
                user_email:{
                    required:"Enter your email address",
                    email:"Enter valid email address"
                },
            },
            errorClass: "help-inline",
            errorElement: "span",
            highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

this is PHP part that I wanna replace with Javascript:

```
        <?php if($_POST) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-success">
  Thanks, we have your info, and expect our contact really soon!
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) from [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: or $.ajax() for more options

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly need. Any popup is an action of the client-side Javascript!

Comment: can it be something like this

    <script>
 $("#registerHere").submit(function(event){
  document.write(<div class="alert alert-success"> Thanks, we have your info, and expect our contact really soon! </div>);
 });
 </script>

Comment: In this case you are able use onsubmit event, but it is not sure that data is delivered or not!

Answer (score 1):

The logic you are talking about is not correct. The ear of your [server-side](/questions/tagged/server-side) is PHP. It is not possible to know that the form posted and the data are delivered to the server without PHP.

Comment: from server side is handled by Python so I just need javascript pop up

Comment: @dzordz Also you will a mean of communication in the server-side Python there to confirm that data are posted. It is a matter of client-server model in web application. The ultimate thing that client-side Javascript is able to know -alone- is submitting the form, but it does not able to know  if the data delivered or not!